Changing v-btn hover effects in vuetify 3
I am having trouble removing the background hover effect, well, manually changing the hover effects of the Vuetify v-btn component.
I have attempted solutions from this github thread(https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3026), and some others as seen below, however, while I can edit the hover effects, this sort of button background opacity remains, i.e if I change it to white which I want, there is some opacity applied to it.
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto" color="grey-lighten-3" max-width="448">
    <v-layout>
      <v-app-bar
        color="white"
        class="h-20 flex justify-center"
      >
        <v-btn class="no-hover font-googlePoppins font-bold leading-loose text-zinc-800"
          variant="text"
          :ripple="false"
        >Home</v-btn>
      </v-app-bar>
    </v-layout>
  </v-card>
</template>
  

<script setup>
import {
  VAppBar,
  VBtn,
  VCard,
  VLayout,
} from 'vuetify/lib/components/index.mjs';

</script>

<style scoped>
.no-hover {
  transition: none !important;
}
.no-hover::before {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.no-hover:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
</style>


The internal DOM structure of a <v-btn> component looks like this (right click a Vuetify button and select "Inspect"):
<button type="button" class="v-btn ...">
  <span class="v-btn__overlay"></span>
  <span class="v-btn__underlay"></span>
  <span class="v-btn__prepend">
    Prepended icon
  </span>
  <span class="v-btn__content">
    Button text
  </span>
  <span class="v-btn__append">
    Appended icon
  </span>
  ::after
</button>

The hover effect is provided by .v-btn__overlay which changes background-color and/or opacity.
To modify the background color dynamically by applying a class to <v-btn>, one needs to target the inner element inside :v-deep(), if the component <style> is scoped:
.no-hover:hover :v-deep(.v-btn__overlay) {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

To understand why, read about how Scoped CSS works in Vue.
If my answer doesn't help, consider adding a runnable minimal reproducible example to the question.
